# 127.0.0.1 Will not work in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost

I have upgraded to Windows 8.1 pro and 127.0.0.1 and my local IP will not resolve to to the IIS 8.5 start page but localhost will.

But it all works in Firefox and Chrome.

I have no idea how to fix this it shows no errors other than this:

This page can’t be displayed

- Make sure the web address 127.0.0.1 is correct.
- Look for the page with your search engine.
- Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Could some one help me figure this out?

Never mind I got it working

I figured it out had to turn off new IE 11 feature  "Enable Enhanced Protected mode"
Now it seams to work fine

Comment: maybe you have to mess around with `hosts` file in `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`  `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)` or you may have a proxy on

Answer (score 14):

Disable the "Enable Enhanced Protected mode" in Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security.
[Advanced settings dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5KLV.png)

Answer (score 9):

To add a site as trusted site in IE, follow these steps:

- In Internet Explorer, click `Tools`, click `Internet Options`, and then click the `Security` tab.
- In the Select a Web content zone to specify its current security settings box, click `Trusted Sites`, and then click `Sites`.
- Disable the `Require Server Verification` option to add HTTP sites.
- Here, add `http://127.0.0.1`, `http://<your IP>`, hence you can access your local server by these addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

- Internet Options
- Connections Tab
- LAN Settings
- Advanced

add localhost to the Proxy Exception list

Answer (score 0):

Add 127.0.0.1 to Trusted Sites

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your answer to add more context and preferably some steps as to how the OP can do this.